# .NET: How to copy data between different classes with the similar members (type & name)?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say we have 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
  public int P1 {set; get;}
  public int P2 {set; get;} 
}

public class B
{
  public int P1 {set; get;}
  public int P2 {set; get;}

  public int P3 {set; get;}
  public int P4 {set; get;} 
}
```

May I convert it in some way to initialize the members of them which have the same name?

I mean if .NET has something to exclude operations like:

```
A.P1 = B.P1
A.P2 = B.P2

B.P1 = A.P1
B.P2 = A.P2
```

and ignore other members...

Is it possible to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude operations like"? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could extract the common properties to an interface.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  int P1 {set; get;}
  int P2 {set; get;}
}

public class A : IMyInterface
{
  public int P1 {set; get;}
  public int P2 {set; get;} 
}

public class B : IMyInterface
{
  public B(IMyInterface i)
  {
    P1 = i.P1;
    P2 = i.P2;
  }
  public int P1 {set; get;}
  public int P2 {set; get;}

  public int P3 {set; get;}
  public int P4 {set; get;} 
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
A a = new A();
a.P1 = 1;
a.P2 = 2;

B b = new B(a);
Console.WriteLine(b.P1); //Outputs 1
Console.WriteLine(b.P2); //Outputs 2
```

EDIT:
Perhaps you could look into the https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper library

Comment: Then the classes would both implement the same interface, so you would be done, no casting required.

Comment: @Terminador not sure what else you'd need to do?

Comment: @Terminador ahh, no, you can't do that I'm afraid

Comment: If both A and B are defined as implementing IMyInterface, sure.  Wait, what's your question.  In the title, you talk about casting.  But then in your question, it sort of looks a little like you're trying to copy data between objects.  Which is it?

Comment: @Simon Could you  finish your code please to demonstrate final goal that I have asked...

Comment: @Terminador I'm not so sure what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Terminador, I asked you if you meant A or B, and you said yes :-).

Comment: @Terminador updated answer to show a way you could initialise one object from another.  Technically you don't need the interface then, but with it you could initialise either A or B from another A or B.

Comment: @dsolimano   Hahahaha :) I think @ S i m o n gave very good approach.

Comment: @Terminador AutoMapper will do what Julien Jacobs answer suggests, but with more features.

Comment: @Terminador, you should definitely use AutoMapper as @Simon suggested. It is very easy, once you reference AutoMapper in your project, call `Mapper.CreateMap<DestinationType, SourceType>();` to initialize the mapping, and then call `Mapper.Map(dest, source);` Where `dest` is of `DestinationType` and `source` is of `SourceType`

Comment: +1 for mentioning Automapper, I saw this question and was about to suggest it.

Answer (score 5):

Using an interface or inheritance are both valid solutions in case you own and can change the classes A and B.

In case you don't, you could use Reflection to copy the properties from an object to another. Something like the above

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
GenericConverter<A,B>.Convert(a, b);


public static class GenericConverter<TInput, TOutput> where TOutput : new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts <paramref name="entity"/> from <see cref="TInput"/> to <see cref="TOutput"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">the object to convert</param>
    /// <returns>The object converted</returns>
    public static TOutput Convert(TInput entity)
    {
        if(entity is Enum)
            throw new NotImplementedException("Entity is an enumeration - Use ConvertNum!");

        TOutput output = new TOutput();

        Type fromType = entity.GetType();
        Type toType = output.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] props = fromType.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            PropertyInfo outputProp = toType.GetProperty(prop.Name);

            if (outputProp != null && outputProp.CanWrite)
            {
                string propertyTypeFullName = prop.PropertyType.FullName;

                object value = prop.GetValue(entity, null);
                outputProp.SetValue(output, value, null);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the classes are not related to each other by inheritance, you can't cast one to another.

You can do so if `B` inherited from `A` - it would then automatically get the properties defined on `A`.

In regards to your examples:

```
A.P1 = B.P1
A.P2 = B.P2

B.P1 = A.P1
B.P2 = A.P2
```

Since the types of all `P1` and `P2` members are `int`, you can always do such assignment, as the properties are public and have public getters and setters. No casting is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to have something like that? If two classes are related to each other, you might want to inherit them:

```
public class A
{
  public int P1 {set; get;}
  public int P2 {set; get;} 
}

public class B : A
{

  public int P3 {set; get;}
  public int P4 {set; get;} 
}
```

Comment: It could be... But I like more solution of @Simon   Thank you anyway!